# How to open div before the class close the div after another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append div with class before the `.left`. Its must be close after the `.right`. I have tried like below but its automatically close in same line.

I also tried wrap() but no luck.

HTML

```
<!-- <div class="group"> -->
<div class="tp left arrow">Left</div>
<div class="tp bullets">
    <div class="round">1</div>
    <div class="round">2</div>
    <div class="round">3</div>
    <div class="round">4</div>
    <div class="round">5</div>
</div>
<div class="tp right arrow">right</div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

JS

```
$( ".left" ).before( "<div class='group'>" );
$( ".right" ).after( "</div'>" );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `wrapAll()` method for that

```
$(".left,.bullets,.right").wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>")
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9o6uj4L/5/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.tp').wrapAll('<div class="group" />')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tp left arrow">Left</div>
<div class="tp bullets"><div class="round">1</div><div class="round">2</div><div class="round">3</div><div class="round">4</div><div class="round">5</div></div>
<div class="tp right arrow">right</div>
```